# before_validation, on: :save vs before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a model where I may need to manipulate some of its attributes before saving it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :email

  # before_validation :set_name_from_email, on: :save
  # OR
  # before_save :set_name_from_email

  def set_name_from_email
    self.name ||= email
  end

end
```

If I had to `validates :name, presence: true` then of course this would have to go in a `before_validation`. But if there is (as the code stands now) no chance of the callback affecting the validity of the object, is it better to put it in `before_save`?

It seems neater to have all your data manipulating callbacks in either one or the other bucket, in case the code changes and the callback now COULD affect validity, but then again it seems bad to run callbacks unnecessarily when calling things like `.valid?`.

Any strong opinions either way?

Comment: "Any strong opinions either way?" -- Nope. It doesn't matter. Just do whatever feels better to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I would place all data manipulating in the `before_save` since it is logical to have all data manipulations in one place (before saving).

However, if you would have validations on the name field in the future (even when the data manipulation does not affect validity) you should put your data manipulation in a `before_validation`, because you don't want storing data y in your db while validating data x.

You can read more about this here:
http://bashar3a.com/2011/09/02/activerecord-callback-gotchas-before_save-vs-before_validate/

Answer (score 3):

Since you are not actually validating anything, but manipulating an attribute, you should use a `before_save` callback.

Custom validation methods usually add an error to the model, and your `set_name_from_email` is not doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Unless **you want to validate the value that your own method assigned to "name"**, you can use both.

But if your method can result to an invalid name you should use before_validation.